# Programmatically creating an Excel Hyperlink to a defined name

Tags: excel, hyperlink, vba

I have an Excel sheet where I'm using the HYPERLINK function with a defined named, i.e. `=HYPERLINK("#IS_Detail_CM_Entity01_Revenue",SUM($A1:$A15)`.  I have hundreds of these formulas in this particular workbook.  I want to publish this file as a .pdf, but the conversion process does not create links in Adobe based on the Excel Hyperlink function.

I've tried using the "`ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Cell,Cell.Value`" code, but I can't get it to work with the defined names I'm using.

Is there a way to do this?  I'm really not looking forward to defining each of these links manually.

Comment: I believe you need to convert the hyperlink to a fully qualified path that other programs can understand.  Not sure of a way to do this automatically however.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation when I need to generate hyperlinks based on a cell range content.
What I have done:

1. Generated the links based on the cell range using the HYPERLINK Excel function
2. Copied the generated column in Word:this is getting rid of the formula and generates a table with links.
3. Copied the content from Word into Excel. Now the content of the cell in Excel is the display text and the cell has the hyperlink build it.

Answer (score 0):

Say we have hyperlinks in a worksheet implemented with the **HYPERLINK()** function using Defined Names.  For example:

```
=HYPERLINK("#MyCell","destination")
```

and we want to convert them to Inserted Hyperlinks.  Select the cells containing the formulas and run this small macro:

```
Sub HyperConverter()
    Dim r As Range, s As String, rLook As Range
    Dim DQ As String
    DQ = Chr(34)
    Set rLook = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas), Selection)
    If Not rLook Is Nothing Then
        For Each r In rLook
            s = r.Formula
            If InStr(s, "HYPERLINK") > 0 And InStr(s, "#") > 0 Then
                ary = Split(s, DQ)
                r.Clear
                ss = Mid(ary(1), 2, 9999)
                ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=r, Address:="", SubAddress:=ss, TextToDisplay:=ary(3)
            End If
        Next r
    End If
End Sub
```